# GUI to windows service

Tags: c, visual-c++

I have implemented a service which transfers the file using socket to another computer. I want to provide GUI for the service. How may i do this?

My service is implemented in the C.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Without any code this question is much too broad, IMHO.

Comment: By `service`, do you mean a Windows service?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Service with GUI monitor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159332/windows-service-with-gui-monitor)

Answer (score 0):

Create a GUI app with whatever GUI libraries you favour, e.g. WinForms, MFC, VCL, ATL, Win32, Qt etc. Then communicate with your service using some form of IPC. Since you are already using sockets they would seem an obvious choice.

Answer (score 0):

On modern versions of Windows (2008/Vista+) you can't show a GUI from a service, so your GUI will have to be a separate process which will have to communicate with the service using some kind of IPC mechanism.  You might use [memory mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and regular windows messages.