# How to Debug Windows Service written in VC++ in VS2008?

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, windows-services

HI,

How to Debug Windows Service written in VC++ in VS2008 ?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

- [`DebugBreak()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679297%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to break your code whereever you want.
  or
- `Debug Flags` utility that comes as a part of [Windbg Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009) to break as soon as a particular process starts.

Comment: Also checkout [another similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125964/easier-way-to-start-debugging-a-windows-service-in-c).

Comment: But these all are in C# , I want in VC++. DebugBreak is only breaking the code i want to debug the Service code

Comment: @Swapnil ok, I didn't notice the other question was in c#. But both the options that I mentioned will work for any Windows based c++ code. Once your service process breaks, why can't you debug it? All you need to do is then supply your debug symbols and start debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I've previously written up a number of debugging tips for Windows services in C++ here: [Convert a C++ program to a Windows service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554047/convert-a-c-program-to-a-windows-service/1554405#1554405)