# Make a console application into a service?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, service

I have a native c++ application which is the server for my game. I currently have it as a scheduled task on my server,. but it really should be a service from what I read.

Is there away in Visual Studio 2008 to compile as a service instead of a console app?

I don't need to see the console window, the app logs everything to a file.

Thanks

Comment: Create a service project and include the code in it

Comment: There is [a very simple example here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppWindowsService-cacf4948) if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't "compile it as a service" by changing compiler options, you'll have to change the code of you app (to start with, services don't use "main" but "ServiceMain" as an entry point...)

Possible duplicate of: [Convert a C++ program to a Windows service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554047/convert-a-c-program-to-a-windows-service).

Maybe the easiest way to achieve what you want without chaning your program is to use a "service wrapper", a special kind of program which can run your console program as as a service. One of the most known is [srvany](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890) from the Microsoft Resource kit, but there are also alternatives (like e.g. [nssm](http://nssm.cc/))