# Run an executable as service in C++

Tags: c++, windows, service, exe, msvc12

I created a `Win32Console` application using `MSVS2013` and it was compiled successfully. Now I tried creating a service using `CreateService` and binary path was set to the path of the above produced executable. Though I was able to create the service, I cannot start it using `StartService`. The error code `1053` is thrown each time. I tried using `sc.exe` and also tried to start the service manually from `Services`. The same error is shown. How can I solve it now?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a C++ program to a Windows service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554047/convert-a-c-program-to-a-windows-service)

Comment: @0123456789: No..its just a `C++` application.Can I convert this exe to service?or start this exe from a service?

Comment: @NathanOliver: I have gone through that question several times.But was not sure how to implement it..

Comment: @Jackz Can you give an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that gives the same behavior.

Comment: @NathanOliver: U mean example of creating the `exe`?a simple C++ application?

Comment: @Jackz I am saying that if you followed the link provided in my dupe suggestion and you are getting the 1053 error then can you provide the code that you used to generate the service.  Don't post all of the code but the minimum necessary to duplicate the problem.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I couldn't completely get the info provided in that link. Must be because of my low knowledge in `Services` and and its implementation. Will try it tonight.

Comment: An ordinary application is not a service and cannot be directly used as one.  You can either rewrite the application so that it is a service, or make use of a third-party service that runs applications, e.g., srvany or NSSM.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a [ServiceMain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685138(v=vs.85).aspx).
[Here is a sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687414(v=vs.85).aspx).
If you want to execute a non-service application you can use [psexec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You have collision with SC- manager and your function inside application start service

your name of the function service dispatcher table for service;)
prevent from error 1053  if call was send not from SC - manager
C++ code:

```
if(argc < 2)           
  {
     if(!Service_Dispatcher_Table())            
     {
       std::cout<<"ERROR :"<< GetLastError();
     }
 }
 else
 { 
     //your command line "argc" 
 }
```

//here your commands or function : startservice();